# Need help with discrete mathematics (two player games)

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am having trouble with this Tac Tix game.Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any hint that you've attempted the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
The strategy of each player to predict the opponent move :
The best way to do that is to consider the sum of the markers removed by the two players at each turn, and to make it constant (let say the value is $M$).

Therefore if it's your opponent's turn, you want him to face a grid with $M*k+1$ markers left ($k$ is the number of turns left so $k \in \mathbb{N}$).

Now you need to find the value of $M$ to find who's going to win.